# Как правильно поставить ударение в имени для человека Кремень?

Tags: орфоэпия

Книга "Листы каменной книги", там был главный охотник Кремень.
Как бы его имя звучало в жизни, с каким ударением?
КрЕмень или КремЕнь?
Если звать человека по имени Кремень, то как?

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 1):

На имена собственные правила поставновки ударения не распространяются.
Точное ударение может указать только сам носитель. Это правило не только языковое, но и этикетное.

В нарицательном существительном ударение на втором слоге - крем**е**нь.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ